# VBA macro to find Sheet count in a directory

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not good with VBA at all but I was curious to know if there is a way to count the amount of worksheets in a workbook that's looped for all the files in a folder.

For example, A1 list the file names and B1 shows the count of sheets.

```
A1       B1
book1    5
book2    6
```

currently have this code set up and need to adjust it

```
Sub ListAllFile()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = Worksheets.Add

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("W:\101g-19 (4.20.18) - Copy\")
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & " are:"


For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
    'ADD A WORKSHEET AND PASTE "=SHEETS()" in A1 the copy value of a1 in to list
    'close files with out saving

Next

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: that doesnt add a page then run the Sheets function and copy it.  the only similiarity is the looping through files and im okay on that portion

Comment: You add a worksheet by using `WorkSheets.Add`, and you add the count by opening the file and reading `WorkSheets.Count()`. You're also not *okay on that portion*, because you're needlessly using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` in VBA where it's absolutely not needed, as VBA has native functionality to retrieve a list of files in a folder and open the workbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the below - note that you should run this from inside of a blank worksheet

```
Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook

Dim folderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim J As Long
Dim N As Long
Dim lc As Long
Dim lr As Long

'UPDATE FOLDER PATH OF WHERE XLS FILES ARE LOCATED
folderPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test\" 'change to suit

J = 2

'   Column Headers
    CurrentWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Filename"
    CurrentWB.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "# of Sheets"

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

'YOU CAN CHANGE TO BE ANY FILE TYPE BUT CURRENTLY SET TO .XLSX
Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)



'       Counts Per Worksheet
    N = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    CurrentWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & J).Formula = Filename
    CurrentWB.Sheets(1).Range("B" & J).Formula = N


'       Close Temporary Workbook
    TempWB.Close False

    J = J + 1
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, open the file (assuming they are all excel here) and get the count of worksheets.

Something like:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    writeCell = ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    writeCell.Value = objFile.Name
    'ADD A WORKSHEET AND PASTE "=SHEETS()" in A1 the copy value of a1 in to list
    'close files with out saving

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name)
    writeCell.Offset(,1).value = wb.Worksheets.Count()
    wb.Close(false)

Next
```

Comment: `writeCell.Value = objFile.Name` says there is a a error with that now

Comment: Be sure to check if the file is "*.xls" before you try to open it

Comment: Perhaps `Set WriteCell = ws.Cells....` Make sure to declare writeCell at the top of the code `Dim WriteCell as Range` and `Dim wb as Workbook`. That should help identify errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ListallFiles()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = "C:\Temp\"     ' Change folder path. Ensure that folder path ends with "\"
    Dim oWB As Workbook
    Dim oWS As Worksheet

    ' Get the first excel file name from specified folder
    sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*.xls*")

    ' Add a worksheet
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With oWS

        ' Set folder name in the new sheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "The file found in " & sFolderPath & " are:"

        ' Loop through all excel files in the specified folder
        Do While Len(Trim(sFileName)) > 0

            ' Open workbook
            Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName)

            ' Set workbook details in the file
            .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = sFileName
            .Range("B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = oWB.Worksheets.Count

            ' Close workbook
            oWB.Close False

            ' Clear workbook object
            Set oWB = Nothing

            ' Get next excel file
            sFileName = Dir()
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Above UDF should open all files in the specified folder and give you the number of worksheets in each workbook on a new worksheet